# Why does GHC take so long to link?

Tags: haskell

```
>cabal update
>cabal install cabal-install
.......
[43 of 44] Compiling Distribution.Client.Install ( Distribution/Client/Install.hs, dist/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Distribution/Client/Install.o )
[44 of 44] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, dist/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/cabal/cabal ..
```

Then I will wait for a VERY long time for it to finish linking.

Answer (score 12):

Very likely it's the linker itself. The standard `ld` from binutils is known to be slow. If you want to speed things up (and live a bit on the edge), try installing the [Gold linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29). On Ubuntu (and I assume Debian), that would be:

```
sudo apt-get install binutils-gold
```

I've been using it on my home system for a while now, no issues yet.

Comment: It's true that `ld` is slow, but it doesn't help that, since ghc does static linking and tries to link in a lot of stuff, there's a lot of work for the linker to do.  On my slightly old macbook with 1GB ram, `ld` will often run out of memory and start swapping.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm sure there's something GHC could do to help, I was merely pointing out some low-hanging fruit.

Comment: @John L: Well, if it's slow because GHC is doing more linking than necessary with a linker that's slower than necessary, there are two obvious ways to improve the overall result, but only one that doesn't require messing with GHC's internals. ;]

Comment: @C. A. McCann: true enough.  But if standard `ld` is the only available linker for your system (OS X for me), then your options are mess with GHC or mess with your linker.  Coincidentally, I've learned much more about linkers than I ever thought I would over the past month...

Comment: @Michael Snoyman: you're absolutely correct that it's the first thing to try.  I'm basically griping because the linking step is often slow for me as well, and gold isn't an option for non-ELF systems.

Comment: Wow, order of magnitude difference. Excellent suggestion.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman There is [this problem you reported](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/GHC-7-4-and-binutils-gold-td5103972.html) concerning GHC not working with gold. How did you get this to work - is it fixed in recent GHCs?

Comment: I found a way to do this, see my answer below (which code that doesn't fit in a comment).

Comment: GHC will do run-time linker detection soon (probably 7.8): http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/6063#comment:19

Answer (score 7):

This should be a comment, but I cannot format code like this in comments:

I managed to use gold as the linker used by GHC, working around standard ghc-with-gold errors like `/usr/bin/ld.gold: --hash-size=31: unknown option`, by installing `binutils-gold` (as suggested in Michael Snoyman's answer) and then replacing the symlink `/usr/bin/ld` by the following script (made executable with `chmod +x`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys
import os
import subprocess


tofilter = [
    "--hash-size",
    "--reduce-memory-overheads",
]

filtered = [ a for a in sys.argv if not any(a.startswith(p) for p in tofilter) ]
filtered[0] = "/usr/bin/ld.gold"

subprocess.check_call(subprocess.list2cmdline(filtered))
```

Note that trying to set the linker with `ghc -pgml /usr/bin/ld.gold` or `ghc -pgml /usr/bin/ld.whateverElse` is not sufficient because the argument to `-pgml` needs to be a replacement for GCC, not LD. GHC calls GCC, which calls `/usr/bin/ld`; this is why the above script works.

Comment: Will not be necessary with upcoming GHC releases (probably 7.8): http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/6063#comment:19

Comment: So looking forward to that.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll try this workaround. What's strange is that according to comments [here](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/6063), linker detection is supposed to happen when you `configure` a bindist, but I haven't found that to be the case when I am working from a bindist that I compiled from a source distribution. Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: This should use `subprocess.check_call`, not `os.system` as the latter will perform shell expansions that would be otherwise left unexpanded. I just spent about two days trying to track down this one.

Comment: @bgamari Ok, using `subprocess.check_call` now.

Comment: On ubuntu 13.10, ghc 7.6.3 running `cabal build` I got `OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long`. When I checked there were 305 different flags passes to `ld.gold`, by the looks of things most of them were dependencies. I've not a clue what caused it to not work when passed to `subprocess.list2cmdline` but I managed to dodge it by using this line of bash instead: `/usr/bin/ld.gold \`echo "$*" | sed 's/--hash-size=\S*//' | sed 's/--reduce-memory-overheads//'\``. It does the same as the script above, filtering out --hash-size and --reduce-memory-overheads.

Answer (score 3):

GHC will by default create a standalone library/executable (static linking).

Dynamic linking has been supported for a while now, so you could try turning it on. With less work to do, the linker is likely to be much faster. On the other hand, you'll need to make sure that at execution time the dynamic libraries you rely on are available (LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable on Linux).