# Cannot start with bnfc

Tags: ghc, gold-linker

I'm following a short [bnfc example](http://bnfc.digitalgrammars.com/), to generate an haskell parser. When I launch the make command I get these errors:

```
latex DocCalc.tex; dvips DocCalc.dvi -o DocCalc.ps
/bin/sh: 1: latex: not found
/bin/sh: 1: dvips: not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

I don't have latex installed, neither divps (what is the last?). So I removed the line:

```
latex DocCalc.tex; dvips DocCalc.dvi -o DocCalc.ps
```

in the make file, because I don't know exactly the names of the needed packages to install, and because I don't need documetation files. So I relaunch the make command, and this time I get these errors, after the building phase:

```
Linking TestCalc ...
/usr/bin/ld: --hash-size=31: unknown option
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Can you help me to understand what I'm missing?

Comment: This looks like https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/6063

Comment: Yeah, it seems my problem. I upgraded ghc with "apt-get upgrade ghc", but the problem persist...

Answer (score 0):

As kosmikus said, it's a problem caused from ghc and the gold linker.

I resolved my problem reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046319/haskell-ghc-compiling-linking-error-not-creating-executable-linux)